# VSCode for JavaScript how to disable "package" autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using `p(...)` as a shortcut for `console.log(...)` in JavaScript. And every time I use it VSCode auto-comlete it into `package(...)`.

Seems like there are couple of different code generation and JS variables auto-comlete support. Is there a way to know where that `package` come from and how to disable it? Visually it looks like that:

[image]

Comment: If you don't find a way to do exactly what you want, "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top"  will help.  It should put your "p" snippet on top of  "package, etc."

Comment: And see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/10565 - there are temporary ways to deal with this but no real solution.